# Allow inline scripts CSP with Apache

Tags: php, apache, content-security-policy

I have to enable CSP and allow running inline scripts.
I have been trying various things but I am still getting CSP warning in developer console.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”)

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

I have been trying to implement CSP with nonce, and have below in my apache settings.

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so //generates unique nonce for each http request

Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'unsafe-eval';"
```

The above apache settings generates a unique id which I am then passing to my inline JS `<script nonce="<?= $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'] ?>">`

But am still getting errors in console.

```
Content Security Policy: Couldn’t parse invalid host 'nonce-X@KFhfNmoeAb3yfsstqrgQAAAMc'
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”)
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)
```

Please note that I don't intend to use **unsafe-inline** as that would not solve the purpose of CSP.

From Granty's answer I have now tried using the csp_nonce module.
And have below in my apache config

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule cspnonce_module modules/mod_cspnonce.so
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e' 'unsafe-eval';"
```

The inline script tags now contains the CSP_NONCE variable.

However I am still getting some errors in the console.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

Any help appreciated, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_unique_id` is not suitable to generate `'nonce'` because of **@** character in the generated ID.

Your `'nonce-X@KFhfNmoeAb3yfsstqrgQAAAMc'` token has [non allowed character @](https://csplite.com/csp/test322/#test).
You can use [mod_cspnonce](https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce) instead of. It generates valid nonce values via crypto algo according to CSP spec.

PS: as I see `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”)` - be careful when use `default-src` as fallback for `script-src`.
Firefox has a bug: `'nonce-value'` does [not override](http://csplite.com/csp/test253/) `'unsafe-inline'` in `default-src` directive.

Comment: Thanks @granty..I tried using the mod_cspnonce module instead. And now I have Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e' 'unsafe-eval';"  And am getting some errors Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Can you please help?

Comment: `mod response` should substitute the `%{CSP_NONCE}e` to a real generated value. Did you add `LoadModule cspnonce_module modules/mod_cspnonce.so` to the `httpd.conf`? And `<script nonce="<?php echo $ _SERVER ['CSP_NONCE']; ?>">` do insert real `value` into?

Comment: Till this day i try to work strict with csp, but even though i use nonce on <script> tag => the script is blocked due to inline code. i don't understand why, but there is an document.onload event, which, i didn't see any suitable csp compliant replacement. any ideas here?.